# npm WARN tarball tarball data for jqwidgets-framework@8.1.4 seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time

Tags: npm-install, jqwidget

I am getting intermittent issue during installing jqwidgets. Most of the time things working as expected but sometime I got below error

```
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] minimatch has the following vulnerability: 1 high. Go here for more details: https://www.npmjs.com/advisories?search=minimatch&version=2.0.10 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for jqwidgets-framework@8.1.4 (sha512-9jOhaB4hQ59pRRBk90EbzmGeEXHsBaZ+XIT2/+6Ulls4btDY6nFO31FFR7CNseWeNnqn22qQUkZcfnj084FrsQ==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
Cannot contact dcs-jenkins-s13: java.lang.InterruptedException
npm WARN The package @types/node is included as both a dev and production dependency.

npm ERR! path /mnt/nfs_jenkins/dcs-jenkins-s13/workspace/d_MyProject/node_modules/.staging/jqwidgets-framework-f4ca9813/jqwidgets-ng/dist/esm2015/jqxnavigationbar/.nfs0000000002d7d99900003970
npm ERR! code EBUSY
npm ERR! errno -16
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink '/mnt/nfs_jenkins/dcs-jenkins-s13/workspace/myproject/node_modules/.staging/jqwidgets-framework-f4ca9813/jqwidgets-ng/dist/esm2015/jqxnavigationbar/.nfs0000000002d7d99900003970'
```

Comment: You're trying to install an old version. May be there was an issue with this package which is already resolved.

Comment: @scripto this is an intermittent issue some times it happens and sometimes not